# between function with dates

Tags: mysql, date, between

I am trying to run a sql asking for the results between date ranges. I have `table_1` with columns

- `date date`
- `company varchar(50)`
- `ref_no varchar(50)`

My sql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-02-27' AND '2015-03-13';
```

I have also tried running this...

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('2015-02-27' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-03-13 AS DATE);
```

The results return with nothing although I know I have data in there between these two dates.

Any suggestions??

Comment: You are likely getting an error because date is a reserved word. You need to escape the field name with back ticks but I would STRONGLY suggest your change the field name.

Comment: Good reason to enable or retrieve error messages.   How are you executing this query?

Comment: I am just running a 'SELECT' query. I don't get any errors; just no results.

Comment: I don't understand what 'back ticks' means?? I tried changing the column name from 'date' to 'occurrence' but still no results??

Comment: what version of sql are you using? cant see anything wrong with the query itself

Comment: have you tried `SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE('2015-02-27') AND DATE('2015-03-13');` ?

Comment: can you show your table data please, specifically that which you think should be matching that query?

Comment: It's not that "date" is a reserved word. [See your query running OK as is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/602c4/1). I suspect either you're selecting from the wrong table, as is often the case the right table but the wrong database. PS @mike see link - it isn't the column name (although I agree that such names should be avoided).

Comment: how can I display my results here for you pala?

Comment: Just cut and paste some rows from your table that you think SHOULD be returned by the query, and also the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's due to the data being loaded into the table_1 externally; I have since entered the data individually with MySql and it works fine. **Must be a problem with the external data.**